# Rust cannot index into a value of type 'datatype<{integer}, {integer}>`

Tags: indexing, rust

I have the following:

```
impl<'a, K: Hash + Eq, V> Index<K> for &'a LFUCache<K, V> {
    type Output = V;
    fn index(&self, index: K) -> &Self::Output {
        self.get(index).unwrap()

    }
}
```

This compiles fine.

Now when I do:

```
let mut lfu = LFUCache::new(2);
lfu.set(1, 1);
lfu[1] == 1;
```

I get an error:

```
cannot index into a value of type `LFUCache<{integer}, {integer}>`
   --> src/lib.rs:154:9
    |
154 |         lfu[1] == 1;
    |         ^^^^^^
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Just curious, but is the `'a` annotation in your example intentional? If not I think you might want to try `impl<K: Hash + Eq, V> Index<K> for LFUCache<K, V>`.

Answer (score 0):

A number without any suffix in rust has no specific int type, (it could be any of i8,i16,i32,u8, etc) so the rust compiler can't infer which one you want your cache to hold. There are three ways to fix this:

1. Explicitly specify when constructing it: `LFUCache::<i32,i32>::new(2)`
2. Explicitly specifying the type of the binding. `let mut lfu: LFUCache<i32,i32> =`
3. Explicitly specify the type of int you are inserting with a suffix:`lfu[1i32] = 1i32;`

I believe option 2 is the most idiomatic in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by making it: `impl<'a, K:Hash+Eq, V>  Index<K> for LFUCache<K, V> {...}`